# Adding settings to android app

Tags: android

This is definitely a noob question. I've followed the instructions here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity and when I click on settings, nothing happens.

Here's what I have in MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
}
```

Then I have a new java file called PrefsActivity.java

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}    }
```

Then I have res/xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="face_up"
    android:title="@string/face_up"
    android:summary="@string/face_up_desc"
    android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am trying to make it compatible with minsdk 7 if possible. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to open your activity when you click on your settings button. If your using an action bar, use something like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. How was I to know this was required? Is there more information somewhere. Thanks

Comment: @batoutofhell I agree, it should probably be in the tutorial. Have you gone through the [Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) lessons? All the fundamentals of app development are there. Whenever you want to go to a new activity, you have to call an intent to open that activity. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In your main Activity

```
   // Ensure the right menu is setup
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Start your settings activity when a menu item is selected
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
             Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class);
             startActivity(settingsIntent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```